# Cannot import variables from sass file in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I have a `variables.scss` file that holds all of my sass variables in my root. I want to import it in my other scss files so that I can use these variables:

```
@import "/variables.scss";
```

However when I run the project, I get the following error:

> Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/index.scss':
>   File to import not found or unreadable: /variables.scss. Load path: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/minima-2.5.0/_sass on line 1

What am I doing wrong and how can I properly import my sass variables. here is my `config_.yml` file:

```
# Welcome to Jekyll!
#
# This config file is meant for settings that affect your whole blog, values
# which you are expected to set up once and rarely edit after that. If you find
# yourself editing this file very often, consider using Jekyll's data files
# feature for the data you need to update frequently.
#
# For technical reasons, this file is *NOT* reloaded automatically when you use
# 'bundle exec jekyll serve'. If you change this file, please restart the server process.

# Site settings
# These are used to personalize your new site. If you look in the HTML files,
# you will see them accessed via {{ site.title }}, {{ site.email }}, and so on.
# You can create any custom variable you would like, and they will be accessible
# in the templates via {{ site.myvariable }}.
title: Project
email: your-email@example.com
description: >- # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Write an awesome description for your new site here. You can edit this
  line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document head meta (for
  Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description.
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: jekyllrb
github_username:  jekyll

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-paginate-v2

collections:
  posts:
    output: true
    permalink: /releases/:path

permalink: pretty

sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: compressed
future: true 
published: true
# Exclude from processing.
# The following items will not be processed, by default. Create a custom list
# to override the default setting.
# exclude:
#   - Gemfile
#   - Gemfile.lock
#   - node_modules
#   - vendor/bundle/
#   - vendor/cache/
#   - vendor/gems/
#   - vendor/ruby/

############################################################
# Site configuration for the Jekyll 3 Pagination Gem
# The values here represent the defaults if nothing is set
pagination:

  # Site-wide kill switch, disabled here it doesn't run at all 
  enabled: true

  # Set to 'true' to enable pagination debugging. This can be enabled in the site config or only for individual pagination pages
  debug: false

  # The default document collection to paginate if nothing is specified ('posts' is default)
  collection: 'posts'

  # How many objects per paginated page, used to be `paginate` (default: 0, means all)
  per_page: 5

  # The permalink structure for the paginated pages (this can be any level deep)
  permalink: '/page/:num/' # Pages are index.html inside this folder (default)
  #permalink: '/page/:num.html' # Pages are simple html files 
  #permalink: '/page/:num' # Pages are html files, linked jekyll extensionless permalink style.

  # Optional the title format for the paginated pages (supports :title for original page title, :num for pagination page number, :max for total number of pages)
  title: ':title - page :num'

  # Limit how many pagenated pages to create (default: 0, means all)
  limit: 0

  # Optional, defines the field that the posts should be sorted on (omit to default to 'date')
  sort_field: 'date'

  # Optional, sorts the posts in reverse order (omit to default decending or sort_reverse: true)
  sort_reverse: true

  # Optional, the default category to use, omit or just leave this as 'posts' to get a backwards-compatible behavior (all posts)
  category: 'posts'

  # Optional, the default tag to use, omit to disable
  tag: ''

  # Optional, the default locale to use, omit to disable (depends on a field 'locale' to be specified in the posts, 
  # in reality this can be any value, suggested are the Microsoft locale-codes (e.g. en_US, en_GB) or simply the ISO-639 language code )
  locale: '' 

 # Optional,omit or set both before and after to zero to disable. 
 # Controls how the pagination trail for the paginated pages look like. 
  trail: 
    before: 2
    after: 2

  # Optional, the default file extension for generated pages (e.g html, json, xml).
  # Internally this is set to html by default
  extension: html

  # Optional, the default name of the index file for generated pages (e.g. 'index.html')
  # Without file extension
  indexpage: 'index'

############################################################
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use only *relative basenames* to import:

```css
@import "variables";

// or if you've nested partials
@import "subdirectory/partial_name";
```

Secondly, if you're using `sassc` gem, ensure that you're using at least `sassc-2.1.0` in your bundle. (Run `bundle show` to check). Or if you're using the deprecated `sass` gem, then continue using that until you can upgrade.

Lastly, ensure that your *scss partial* doesn't have unclosed parentheses.

---

### **UPDATE**

Jekyll expects to find partials to import from in the configured `sass_dir` (which is `_sass` by default).
So, you've to ensure that the path `_sass/variables.scss` exists either at your source directory or within the theme-gem you're using.

Comment: i tried with the relative basename and it still doesn't work and it gives me this error. I don't use sassc gem.

Comment: There isn't much info here to go for. If you have your site's source code hosted somewhere like GitHub or Gitlab, one could take a look.. otherwise, it would just lead to speculations.

Comment: Yes, I updated my question with the project repo URL

Comment: Unable to access the repo. Please provide or ask your client to grant me read-only permissions.

Comment: I can give them to you, can you tell me your email so that I can invite you?

Comment: I didn't encounter any errors while building the site. You may run `bundle exec jekyll build --trace` and send the output to me via email.

Comment: My bad,I hadn't pushed my changes to the repo, only had them locally, I did that and now you should be able to replicate the issue. I also sent you the output

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide the hints to solve this issue.